# Converting Function To Maybe Type

Tags: haskell, fold, option-type

I am trying to convert a function of maximum utilizing a foldr function to one that also incorporates the maybe type. It is originally:

```
maximum' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a  
maximum' = foldr1 (\x acc -> if x > acc then x else acc)
```

It works perfectly with sets, but not with the empty set. I want to convert it to use maybe types instead.

My thought process was:

```
mymax :: (Ord a) => [Maybe a] -> Maybe a 
mymax = foldr (\(Just x) (Just b) -> if ((Just x) > (Just b)) then (Just x) else (Just b)) Nothing
```

It compiles with no errors and works when I give it the empty set. However, when I give it a set with numbers in it, it no longer works! Can someone point me in the right direction on how I can get the functionality of it also getting the maximum from a list of maybes?

I really want to use the foldr function in my solution....

I've now tried:

```
mymax :: (Ord a) => [a] ->  Maybe a 
mymax = foldr (\x b -> if x > b then (Just x) else (Just b)) Nothing
```

But it will not compile:

```
    Couldn't match expected type `Maybe b -> Maybe a'
                with actual type `Maybe a0'
    In the return type of a call of `Just'
    Probable cause: `Just' is applied to too many arguments
    In the expression: (Just x)
    In the expression: if x > b then (Just x) else (Just b)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it in a single `foldr`, we can exploit the fact that `Ord a => Ord (Maybe a)`, that is, any ordering on `a` can be extended to an ordering on `Maybe a`.

We also have `Just x > Nothing`, for all `x :: Ord a => a`.

```
mymax :: (Ord a) => [a] ->  Maybe a 
mymax = foldr (\x b -> let x' = Just x in if x' > b then x' else b) Nothing 
-- equivalently
mymax = foldr (\x b -> let x' = Just x in max x' b) Nothing 
mymax = foldr (\x' b -> max x' b) Nothing . map (\x -> Just x)
mymax = foldr max Nothing . map Just
```

If we want to do minimum, we'll have to do it a bit differently, since `Nothing` is the lower bound for the type `Ord a => Maybe a`, which means that `foldr min Nothing . map Just == const Nothing`, which isn't useful.

```
mymin :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Maybe a
mymin = foldr (\x b -> case b of
    Nothing -> Just x
    Just y  -> Just (min x y)
  ) Nothing
-- which is equivalent to
mymin = foldr (\x b -> Just $ case b of
    Nothing -> x
    Just y  -> min x y
  ) Nothing
mymin = foldr (\x b -> Just $ maybe x (min x) b) Nothing
mymin = foldr (\x -> Just . maybe x (min x)) Nothing
```

Honestly, though, I think pattern matching makes solutions a lot clearer

```
mymax [] = Nothing
mymax (a:as) = Just $ foldr max a as

mymin [] = Nothing
mymin (a:as) = Just $ foldr min a as
```

Comment: My only question is what is the notation "$", I tried googling it, but I'm getting a lot of results about buying haskell books...

Comment: @ZAX maybe you should buy a haskell book then :) joke aside, `$` is a standard application function. `f $ x` is the same as `f x`. It is typically used to eliminate parenthesis. `Just $ foldr max a as` == `Just (foldr max a as)`. Without `$` this quickly gets more complicated with lots more parenthesis to untangle when reading the code. For example, try to place the closing parenthesis in the statement `Just (case b of .....)`, and then try to figure out how to read the code - how to match the ). `$` tells the reader "...and the rest of the expression is the argument of the previous function".

Comment: Also, if you want to look up haskell operators try [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and [hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html)

Answer (score 4):

I think you actually want `mymax` to have type `(Ord a) => [a] -> Maybe a`. Here's a potential implementation that uses pattern matching and your original `maximum'` function:

```
mymax :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Maybe a
mymax [] = Nothing
mymax xs = Just (maximum' xs)
```

Also, [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) is a great resource if you haven't already come across it!

Comment: I'm really trying to use the foldr way of doing it although yes, this does work

Comment: @ZAX the problem with your updated code is that the type of `x` is `a`, and the type of `b` is `Maybe a`, so they cannot be compared.